# Make Webstorm highlight .txt files as HTML

Tags: syntax-highlighting, webstorm

So I have some project files all with .txt extensions which are really HTML templates. I am trying to syntax highlight those .txt files as HTML using Webstorm. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: I fixed the grammar in the body, tweaked the title, changed some irrelevant tags for one that describes what you're actually after, and removed "thanks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `File > Settings > Editor > File Types > HTML files` and add your extension to registered patterns in the right panel.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)